# Why are Sony Xperia Z2 and Galaxy S4 excluded?

Tags: android, galaxy, sony-xperia

I have the following section for supported screens in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <compatible-screens>

        <!-- small devices, all densities -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />

        <!-- average devices, all densities -->
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />

         <!-- larger devices, all densities -->
         <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="large" />
         <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
         <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="large" />
         <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="large" />

         <!-- tablets/extra large devices, all densities -->
         <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
         <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
         <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />
         <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="xlarge" />

   </compatible-screens>
```

In the Google Developer Console, Sony Xperia Z2 and Samsung Galaxy are marked as 'not supported'. How can this be? I basically covered all screen sizes up to xlarge. According to Table 3 at the Android Developer Guide (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) the Sony Xperia (1980x1020 @ 423ppi) and the Samsung Galaxy S4 (1980x1020 @ 441ppi) would be in xlarge/xhdpi, albeit the densities certainly exceed the values in the table. Is there a higher density qualifier that I am not aware of? What other reason would PlayStore have to exclude these devices?

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is also `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi`

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html for details.

Comment: I tried adding these to the section, but AndroidSDK gives me an error in the Manifest: "Error: String types not allowed (at 'screenDensity' with value 'xxhdpi')."

Comment: Found the answer in the thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486763/android-google-play-filtering-out-xxhdpi

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Those devices are `xxhdpi` devices, which you have excluded.